# Meteor: How to render line breaks?

Tags: meteor

I have the following variable: "hello↵↵world". (the value is coming from a textarea)

The problem is when I ask Meteor to display it with {{content}}, everything appears on the same line and the line break are not taken into account.

```
{{content}}

# renders
hello world

# should render
hello
world
```

Comment: maybe `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n` would help?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap with

`<pre>
Any
   amount of
formatting.
</pre>`

Comment: You can apply formatting to the pre tag as well (should probably add a class to pre if you do this).  As usual, there are many ways of solving the same problem.  This is the minimal answer.

Comment: @Bolster You saved my life !!  :D

Answer (score 11):

If you're using bootstrap using the `<pre>` tag will come with some style that you probably don't want... If you want to avoid that you can solve this with some simple CSS:

```
.pre {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

and then just wrap your content with that class:

```
<span class="pre">{{content}}</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

`<pre>` worked fine for me until I had long lines of text. By default it disables line wrapping and long lines break the page layout or are cut off.

You could probably get around it with `white-space: pre-wrap;` but what I ended up doing was create a Spacebars-Helper that escapes the text first and then replaces all breaks with `<br/>`

```
UI.registerHelper('breaklines', function(text, options) {
  text = s.escapeHTML(text);
  text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '<br/>');
  return new Spacebars.SafeString(text);
});
```

I would then use the helper in my templates in the following way:

```
{{breaklines title}}
```

`escapeHTML` is part of Underscore.string, a collection of string manipulation extensions that you can pull in with `meteor add underscorestring:underscore.string`, but any other way of escaping html should work fine as well.

Comment: One other way of escaping text without adding a package is to use the undocumented function `Blaze._escape()`.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to create a handlebar helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'breaklines', (text) ->
    text = text.replace /(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '<br>'
    return text
```

and then to do so: (do not forget the three brackets!)

```
{{{breaklines content}}}
```

Comment: This opens your app up to mischief, with people able to put tags and javascript into text fields.  Yes, you can guard against that, and can argue that you know what the text is coming from.  But generally this is not a solution to casually use.

Comment: Yes you're right. I have changed the accepted answer.

Comment: Not an issue, user added content parsing have to be done server-side anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just use `<br>` it is enough no more troubles.