# Meteor helper: HTML tags in helper

Tags: meteor, line-breaks, helper

I have a Meteor helper that looks like this:

```
"text":function(){
    return "testtesttest <br> testtesttest";
}
```

But the `<br>` is not working (no line break in displayed text), if I use `\n`  instead of `<br>`, I get `testtesttest<br>testtesttest`.

The usage of `<pre>` is not what I'm looking for.

How can I make my helper return a String, that contains line breaks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor: How to render line breaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285310/meteor-how-to-render-line-breaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return text with html markup, you should use {{{ ... }}}.

So use {{{ test }}} instead of {{ test }} in your template.

Answer (score 1):

In your helper,Use `<br>` where you want the line breaks.

In your html, Enclose your helper in triple curly braces

Apply the following CSS to the element containing the text.

```
white-space: pre
```

Or

```
white-space:pre-wrap
```

If alsoyou want text to wrap automatically when necessary