# The text retrieved from the database is showing without the lines

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

retrieving the text from the database doesn't show the new lines in between the text.
the text in the database is called definition. and am retrieving it this way

```
{{knowledge.definition}}
```

what should i do to fetch the text with the new lines?

am using collection2 package to store my text

Comment: If you console.log the text, does it contain \n characters?

Comment: @DavidWeldon yes it contains when i use "db.collectionName.find().pretty()"

Comment: MongoDb stores texts and other fields in binary format - what you put there is what you get. MongoDb is not swallowing the new line symblos in your texts. I guess what you want to achieve is to get a pretty formatted JSON in your client. You should look at the API of your client how to format your JSON in a pretty way.

Comment: @EvgenyS. i know it is not swallowing it because i could see it in the database. my question is how to not omit those new lines when displaying the data. anyways, am looking through what you said

Comment: @user3420180 Sorry, I just want to clarify that you probably mean you lose the new lines not in contents of your text fields but the new lines separating fields in your result, don't you? If so then it is just a matter of formatting JSON. If not and you do actually lose new lines inside retrieved text fields then there might be some bug in mongo client implementation or incorrect use.

Comment: @EvgenyS. yea, can you guide me through it? am still novice. all i managed to find in google when i search for JSON formatting is xml related. am still searching. if you can provide me with links that might help i would appreciate it

Comment: @user3420180 I guess it is JavaScript. So, look at JSON.stringify() method. Just note that it takes an object as the first argument, so if you have a string then first you should use JSON.parse() to make an object and then send it to JSON.stringify(). If you already have an object then use JSON.stringify() as is.

Comment: @EvgenyS. knowledge: function () {
   var itemId = Session.get("itemId");
   return Items.findOne({ _id: itemId});
  }, how will i access the description element and apply the changes you told me before returning it? is it possible!

Comment: @EvgenyS. do you know how to get a specific element in the document which the "_id" known?

Comment: @EvgenyS. okay, i finally managed to return the JSON.stringify and display it. but it shows me "\n" instead of new lines -_-

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285310/meteor-how-to-render-line-breaks). I'm inclined to mark this one as a duplicate, but I'm unsure if it is - you let me know.

Comment: @DavidWeldon yes it is duplicated question. THANK YOU