# How to retrieve a particular element in the document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

using this code i manages to get the whole document

```
Products.findOne({ _id: itemId});
```

i want to get a particular element "description" in that document. to apply JSON.stringify on it before returning it.

How will i do it?

thanks

Comment: Do you want just the description or an object containing the description? Please be very clear in your questions about all of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: @DavidWeldon sorry, i want an object containing the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending on what you want. If you want an object containing just the `_id` and the `description`, then you can do this:

```
var product = Products.findOne(itemId, {fields: {description: 1}});
```

Alternatively, you can use [pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) which does something similar:

```
var product = _.pick(Products.findOne(itemId), '_id', 'description');
```

And if you want an object that only contains the `description` you can do:

```
var product = _.pick(Products.findOne(itemId), 'description');
```

Comment: accepted the answer, it solved my problem in retrieving the description. but after I used JSON.stringify(product); and display the result in the html, i can see the text without the new lines. the new lines are replaced with "\n" do you know how i can show these new lines when displaying the description? thanks

Comment: Yep, have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285310/meteor-how-to-render-line-breaks). There are a couple of techniques presented - hopefully one of them works for you.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/
It has examples on how to limit elements.